Weird definition of `close-enuf?` in Software Design for Flexibility
MIT 6.5151 course code base based on book Software Design for Flexibility has the following definition:
(define (close-enuf? h1 h2 tolerance)
  (n:<= (n:magnitude (n:- h1 h2))
        (n:* .5
             (n:max tolerance flo:ulp-of-one)
             (n:+ (n:magnitude h1)
                  (n:magnitude h2)
                  2.))))

The above is used in (assert-close z1 tolerance z2) (it just does close-enuf? but with some side effects which have no relations with the comparison result). Then it have the following testing cases (Here I only give part of the block reference where (gas-law-volume ...) should have result .02404848592336704 and this is similar for others. Notice here the expected calculation result are all less than 1e4):
    (assert-close .02404848592336704 1e-4
                  (gas-law-volume (psi-to-nsm 14.7)
                                  ((compose celsius-to-kelvin
                                            fahrenheit-to-celsius)
                                   68)
                                  1))
...
    (assert-close 1467.5286508533222 1e-4
                  ((unit:expt (unit:invert inch-to-meter) 3)
                   (gas-law-volume (psi-to-nsm 14.7)
                                   ((compose celsius-to-kelvin
                                             fahrenheit-to-celsius)
                                    68)
                                   1)))

Here n:foo means foo in internal Scheme implementation as the book says:

Because we anticipated varying the meanings of many operators
in the MIT/GNU Scheme system, we made a special set of
operators that name primitive procedures we might need later.
We named the copies with the prefix n:. In MIT/GNU Scheme
the original primitive procedures are always available, with their
original names, in the system-global-environment, so we
could have chosen to get them from there.

If only considering real numbers, then the above returns |h1-h2|<=((|h1|+|h2|+2)/2)*tolerance when tolerance is not very small. Here tolerance may mean relative tolerance as python math.isclose and this JS implementation instead of absolute tolerance as this QA implies.
But as the definition implies, if |h1|+|h2| is very big, then the result may probably return true. So (close-enuf?  1e4 (+ 1 1e4) 1e-4) will return #t.
Then why does the course code base define such a close-enuf?? Does it work better for some cases?

There is no context here. The definition bears some similarity to crude routines that attempt to determine whether a number that has been computed with floating-point rounding is a result that would have equaled another number if it had been computed with real-number arithmetic instead. Such tests are always context-dependent as they introduce false positives and there is no general solution for this problem. But you have given no context for this definition, such as what it is used for or what is known about h1 and h2 and the calculations they have resulted from.

@EricPostpischil Thanks. 1. Could you give one example for "crude routines that attempt to determine whether a number that has been computed with floating-point rounding is a result that would have equaled another number if it had been computed with real-number arithmetic instead."? 2. I updated my post with one testing file.

I prefer not to give an example of such routines because they are usually poorly designed, and no example can be an ideal example of what to use because there is no general solution for this problem. Each case ought to be tailored to its situation. Most attempts at it accept two numbers as “equal” either if they differ by some absolute amount or if they differ by some relative amount…

…  However, the rounding errors that have affected the calculations are generally neither affected solely by some absolute number or by the magnitudes of the final results. They are affected by each magnitude of each intermediate calculation, and a proper determination of how much a floating-point-computed result could differ from its ideal real-number-arithmetic result depends on a numerical analysis of the calculations.

@EricPostpischil Thanks for your detailed description. I have read your answer link and understood the reasons behind. Numerical analysis is beyond what the book I am reading intends to teach, so I won't dig into it.
